# How to resolve "package org.powermock.modules.junit4 does not exist" in intellij maven?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3

I am new to maven. I am trying to import powermock through this import statement.

import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

I have added the following maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

But despite using the dependency, I am getting this error when I do maven clean install
"package org.powermock.modules.junit4 does not exist"

Comment: Have you built on plain command line? Apart from that `mvn clean install` is not necessary only `mvn clean verify`... please show the full pom file...

Comment: check if this dependency jar is downloaded to your local repository, by looking into .m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-module-junit4

Comment: you may need to run "mvn clean install -U" to force it to download the dependency.

Comment: Thank you @khmarbaise , sanjeevRm and David Bezden for you valuable comments. I rebooted my system and did maven install. it downloaded all the power mock dependency jars. It resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

check if this dependency jar is downloaded to your local repository, by looking into `.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-module-junit4`

if dependency is not found in local repository

you can run `mvn clean install -U` it will force update dependencies

it can be from terminal, which requires maven installation path to be set in "Path" environment variable.

can be run from your IDE as well

Comment: Thank you @SanjeevRm. I rebooted my system and did maven install. it downloaded all the power mock dependency jars. It resolved my issue